# SQL query to detect when accumulated value reaches limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, timescaledb, accumulate

Given the following table in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    minutes INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

I am forming a query to detect when the accumulated value of 'minutes' crosses an hour boundary. For example with the following data in the table:

```
time             | minutes
-------------------------
<some timestamp> | 55
<some timestamp> | 4
```

I want to know how many minutes remain before we reach 60 (one hour). In the example the answer would be 1 since `55 + 4 + 1 = 60`.

Further, I would like to know this at insert time, so if my last insert made the accumulated number of minutes cross an "hour boundary" I would like it to return boolean true.

My naive attempt, without the insert part, looks like this:

```
    SELECT
        make_timestamptz(
            date_part('year', (SELECT current_timestamp))::int,
            date_part('month', (SELECT current_timestamp))::int,
            date_part('day', (SELECT current_timestamp))::int,
            date_part('hour', (SELECT current_timestamp))::int,
            0,
            0
        ) AS current_hour,

        SUM(minutes) as sum_minutes
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        sum_minutes >= 60
```

I would then take a row count above 0 to mean we crossed the boundary. But it is hopelessly inelegant, and does not work. Is this even possible? Would be possible to make it somewhat performant?

I am using Timescaledb/PostgreSQL on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . `insert` doesn't really return values.  But you can use a CTE to do the insert and then sum the values after the insert:

```
with i as (
      insert into my_table ( . . . )
          values ( . . . )
          returning *
     )
select ( coalesce(i.minutes, 0) + coalesce(t.minutes, 0) ) > 60
from (select sum(minutes) as minutes from i) i cross join
     (select sum(minutes) as minutes from my_table) t
```

Comment: Why are you using a cross join here? Asking for a friend 

Comment: @LennartRolland . . . As opposed to what?  You could use subqueries in the `select`, but a `cross join` exactly expresses what is happening.

Comment: I get it now. Only took a few days. You Sir, are a certified genius in my book. I don't know if I will use this but it is a thing of beauty. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT` could look like this:

```
WITH cur_sum AS (
   SELECT coalesce(sum(minutes), 0) AS minutes
   FROM my_table
   WHERE date_trunc('hour', current_timestamp) = date_trunc('hour', time)
)
INSERT INTO my_table (time, minutes)
SELECT current_timestamp, 12 FROM cur_sum
RETURNING cur_sum.minutes + 12 > 60;
```

This example inserts 12 minutes at the current time.

Comment: Looks promising, however what if there arn't any rows for the last 3 hours? It seems the cur_sum query only looks at rows with time within the last hour. This is one of the things I struggled with, when there are gaps in the data of more than an hour.

Comment: I added a `coalesce` so that you get 0 in that case.